# RegEx: How to get the file which name has contain hour 13 to 20

Tags: regex, bash

I want to get the file name which name contain the hour between 13 to 20.

Ex. I have below file in folder.

```
$ ls
A_13_a.txt  A_14_a.txt  A_17_a.txt  A_20_a.txt  A_21_a.txt
```

where number represent the hour.

I want to execute the command which will return below name.

```
A_13_a.txt  A_14_a.txt  A_17_a.txt  A_20_a.txt
```

I have tried below command but not giving right output.

```
ls | egrep 'A_[1][3-9]_a.txt | A_[2][0-0]_a.txt'

ls | grep 'A_[1][3-9]_a.txt'
```

Comment: Try `ls | egrep 'A_(1[3-9]|20)_a\.txt'`

Comment: No, I already tried this, this is giving blank output.

Comment: Try with `egrep` and escape the dot.

Comment: wooooooo, its working now, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need  to escape the dot to be parsed as a literal dot and use an *alternation group* `(1[3-9]|20)` with `egrep` like this:

```
ls | egrep 'A_(1[3-9]|20)_a\.txt'
              ^^^^^^^^^^   ^
```

The `(1[3-9]|20)` matches either of the 2 alternatives:

- `1[3-9]`  - `1` followed with a digit from `3` to `9`
- `|` - or
- `20` - a literal char sequence `20`.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is:

```
ls | awk -F_ '{ if ( $2 > 12 && $2 < 21 ) print $0 }'
```